# Problem with setting up xrdp on Lubuntu 13.04

Tags: lubuntu, 13.04, xrdp

After fresh install of Lubuntu 13.04 I did

```
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Now when I log in with remote desktop client from Windows or Ubuntu, I get black and white mesh screen. I followed various help forums like [this one](http://sourceforge.net/p/xrdp/discussion/389417/thread/64949bc2), but nothing worked!

Comment: VNC server is better than that. Because sometimes compiz crashes because of xrdp

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 13.04 is no longer supported for that I'm giving you solution for Ubuntu 12.04 and then I'll add the 14.04 solution later.

#### For Ubuntu 12.04

Use a tricky hack(obligate the xrdp to use the ubuntu-2d session always without searching for other sessions)

Install xrdp:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Now Edit the file `startwm.sh`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

In the end of the script you can find these three lines calling functions above:

```
pre_start
wm_start
post_start
```

All you have is to comment the `wm_start` function by inserting leading # then add the line for needed session.

```
pre_start
#wm_start

gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d

post_start
```

*The `wm_start` function which is responsible for starting the window manager.*

Now save and exit, then restart xdrp:

```
sudo service xrdp restart
```

This should works smoothly. I'm using it since three years ago.

#### For Ubuntu 14.04 and later

Install xrdp same as above

Install XFCE4 or any other supported

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Edit our `.xsession` file in your home:

```
echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
```

Edit  `startwm.sh` file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

In the `wm_start()` Add the line `startxfce4` just directly under:

```
 if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
    . /etc/default/locale
    export LANG LANGUAGE
  fi
```

so the function looks like:

```
wm_start()
{
  if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
    . /etc/default/locale
    export LANG LANGUAGE
  fi

startxfce4


  # debian
  if [ -r /etc/X11/Xsession ]; then
    . /etc/X11/Xsession
    exit 0
  fi
.....

}
```

Now save and exit then restart xrdp.

```
sudo service xrdp restart
```