# Cannot remote desktop from Ubuntu 15.04 to 14.04 lts

Tags: server, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc, remmina

I am able to ssh into my other PC but I am not able to use `Remmina` to do `RDP` or `VNC`. My other PC has `VNC` server installed and I turned it on before trying to connect but its not working.

Am I typing something in wrong? I did reinstall `Remmina` and I used remote desktop viewer as well. Any ideas guys? Cheers!

Comment: In what way is it "not working", exactly? are there any error messages when you try to connect? What VNC server is installed on the other machine, and have you checked its log? How can we guess if you're "typing something in wrong"?

Comment: It says connection to the entered ip. All I did was enter the ip address into the connection bar and tried with bot selecting vnc and rdp. for vnc it says connection was closed right away but for rdp it says connecting

Comment: What do you get if you type **telnet _host_ 5900** -- does it connect and give you the RFB version, or does something else happen?

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop Protocols(Xrdp-VNC-....) are not affected by the OS version. You can connect to any other version. Also this have nothing to do with Remmina. You should be aware of installing packages on your machines.

For xrdp install it:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

To learn how to configure xrdp on Ubuntu please take a look for my answer here: [problem with setting up xrdp on lubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/312466/182026)

Comment: I tried this and this works thank you! I had the packages so the only thing I changed was the text file. the only problem now is that I cannot connect from outside my network. It works with the local ip assigned to that computer. I have port forwarding set up so any connection from the outside would be sent to that pc. I can still ssh into it from outside but not xrdp.